# How to merge dictionaries of different languages for autocorrect?

Tags: google-chrome, dictionary, autocorrect

I'm bilingual, and I'm constantly writing both in Portuguese and English so of course, I would like to have auto-corrector and word suggestion in both languages. I know I can easily change between languages but doing this every few minutes is very annoying.

So how I can merge two dictionaries? So that only one dictionaries have all the words for both languages? I suppose they are kind of a file, that I could edit right?

I googled it and found only about dictionaries for programming languages only or something like that! I would like a solution that can work on Chrome on Windows 7 but i don't want to prevent people to come with solutions for other browser/OS too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this might be to add the word lists from both languages to `Custom Dictionary.txt`.

A wordlist for English can be found in `en_US.dic` and a wordlist for Portuguese (Brazilian) can be found in `pt_BR.dic` within the Chromium source tree and each of which is linked below.

I think the better solution might be to modify one of the built in languages but this will require you to build and use [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/).

In the Chromium tree, you can merge [`en_US.dic`](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/deps/third_party/hunspell_dictionaries/en_US.dic) into [`pt_BR.dic`](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/deps/third_party/hunspell_dictionaries/pt_BR.dic), [`en_US.aff`](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/deps/third_party/hunspell_dictionaries/en_US.aff) into [`pt_BR.aff`](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/deps/third_party/hunspell_dictionaries/pt_BR.aff), and [`en_US.dic_delta`](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/deps/third_party/hunspell_dictionaries/en_US.dic_delta) into [`pt_BR.dic_delta`](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/deps/third_party/hunspell_dictionaries/pt_BR.dic_delta) and rebuild Chromium.

Your `Portuguese (Brazil)` language should then have all the words (and rules) from both English and Portuguese.

If you want to do things more complicated than simply merging two languages, the affix file format is documented over at [affix.readme](http://www.openoffice.org/lingucomponent/affix.readme)

You may also wish to read Chromium's [Editing the spell checking dictionaries](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/editing-the-spell-checking-dictionaries)

Lastly, what you want is being designed into the Chrome browser, and will apparently be called [Adaptive spell checking for multilingual users](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/advancedspellchecker)

Answer (score 1):

Merging two dictionaries is not a good solution: if you misspell a word in one language, and it happens to be a correct word in another language, the merged dictionary won't catch that. I think you actually want something that auto-detects the language in a text field, and sets the spell checking language appropriately.

[Automatic Dictionary Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/automatic-dictionary-switcher/) for Firefox does just that. As far as I know, there is no equivalent extension for Chrome.